# Значения по умолчанию при вставке с помощью PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Такой вопрос, есть дао класс с запросом `insert` последние три поля в базе данных `postgresql` имеют значение `default`,то есть как мне объяснили данные `postgresql` берет автоматически, какие есть способы сделать эти значения в Java?

Пример:

```
public void addSkisql(Skisql skisql) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("insert into clippersql.skisql(nzak,osd_t,osd_c,osd_r,kiz,pri,nvp,naim,nizv,\"user\",datez,user_ip) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            // Parameters start with 1 
            preparedStatement.setString(1, skisql.getNzak());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, skisql.getOsd_t());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, skisql.getOsd_c());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, skisql.getOsd_r());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, skisql.getKiz());
            preparedStatement.setInt(6, skisql.getPri());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, skisql.getNvp());
            preparedStatement.setString(8, skisql.getNaim());
            preparedStatement.setString(9, skisql.getNizv());
            preparedStatement.setString(10, skisql.getUser());
            Date date = Date.valueOf(skisql.getDatez().toString());
            preparedStatement.setDate(11, date);
            preparedStatement.setString(12, skisql.getUser_ip());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае, если задавать null, то при вставке записи будет использоваться дефолтное значение.

```
Integer obj = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
if (obj == null) {
    preparedStatement.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
} else {
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, obj);
}
```

Если СУБД не поддерживает эту возможность, то можно путем модифицирования запроса (составлять запрос с необходимым количеством параметров) либо добавлять хранимую процедуру.

Comment: а не подскажете как правильно применить это к полю `user` - `preparedStatement.setString(10, skisql.getUser());`?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко         if (skisql.getUser() == null) {
            preparedStatement.setNull(10, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setString(10, skisql.getUser());
        }

Comment: а в самом запросе ничего менять не нужно?

Comment: для поля `user` значение принимает пустую строку, а когда пытаюсь для поля `user_ip` сделать так же,  вылетает `exception` и пишет что 12 значение не задано

Comment: @СергейНиконенко приведите значение user_ip перед вызовом и стектрейс ошибки

Comment: то я немного не правильно написал в коде, но факт в том что если эти поля оставлять пустыми при добавлении новой записи в БД, оно не берет дефолтные значения, а передает пустые строки, что user что user_ip

Comment: @СергейНиконенко if (skisql.getUser() == null || str.trim().isEmpty())) {

Comment: вместо `str` мне переменную `user` ставить?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко да, очепятка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65467/discussion-between---and-dayslikethis).

Comment: спасибо большое за потраченное время, получилось сделать так  `preparedStatement.setString(10, skisql.getUser());` закоментил а в запрос вместо `?` написал `default` и все, начало добавлять в базу автоматом, еще раз спасибо большое) может кому поможет, запрос выглядит так `PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("insert into clippersql.skisql(nzak,osd_t,osd_c,osd_r,kiz,pri,nvp,naim,nizv,\"user\",datez,user_ip) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default,default,default)");`